Fulltext search of MS Office files in SQL Server AWS RDS
I'm aware of the filter packs that can be installed at the OS level for a standalone SQL Server instance to gain support fulltext searching of MS Office and PDF files, but is there any way to get support for the latest MS Offices files in a SQL RDS? Current RDS is SQL 2016 compatible. Didn't know if any upgrades gave native support. TIA!
